# Using custom time values for flipbox (datebox) in Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I am using timeflipbox (datebox) for a mobile website based on JQuery Mobile.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: 1]

In the minutes column, I want just the values 00 15 30 and 45 instead of all the numbers from 0 to 60.

Can you help me with this customization?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check section `Date Limiting Options` in documentation:

http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/demos/fullopt.html

You'll need to set `minuteStep: 15` option.